# RxBLELibraries/RxAndroidBle: with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm using RxBLELibraries/RxAndroidBle for connecting mobile-app with peripheral device.

The mobile-app work properly on Xperia, Samsung but always return ERR on device AQOUS R5G.

My problem on AQOUS R5G is as below:

- Step1: Pairing with device: ok.
- Step2: Try to send command to device to get data: always return err "with status 8 (GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION or GATT_CONN_TIMEOUT)"

Because its occurance depent on device so I decided to make an exception for app when release app.

And so, I want to know how it is on other device:
Does any-one here have the same problem? if yes plz share the device name with me and how to fix this problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you get it resolved ?